# Simple stack length

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried reading up on this, and can get the `len()` function to work with everything but my stack. I have tried multiple different ideas, and have a feeling that it is something simple. Does anyone see the issue where I am running into. I have no clue. I would appreciate the help.

```
class HardwareID():
    #empty list created
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
    #push for python
    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.items == []
    #implimented for learning
    def peek(self):
        if not self.is_empty():
            return self.items[-1]

    def get_stack(self):
        return self.items

s = HardwareID()

print ("The stack the right is the top")
s.push("LCD")
s.push("LED")
s.push("Mobile")
s.push("Charger")
s.push("Speaker")
s.push("Mouse")
s.push("Keyboard")
s.push("Laptop")
print (s.get_stack())
print (len(s))
s.pop()
s.pop()
s.pop()
print (s.get_stack())
```

Comment: what about implementing `__len__()` method for your class?

Comment: Did you try `def __len__(self): return len(self.items)`? When asking a question, it's a good idea to post the error `TypeError: object of type 'HardwareID' has no len()`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix to your problem is adding the method below to your class.

```py
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.items)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [`__len__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__len__#object.__len__) method for your `HardwareID` class:

```py
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.get_stack())
```

Implementing this method will achieve the desired behaviour:

```py
s = HardwareID()
print(len(s))  # 0
s.push("A value")
s.push("B value")
print(len(s))  # 2
s.pop()
print(len(s))  # 1
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not realize I had to use the class method. I have now written this in my notebook as a try every time type of thing. Still learning and doing this in a stack method seemed different.